# How to extract node names without doubles

Tags: xslt

I'm wondering if there is an xsl code that could loop through an xml file and extract only the nodenames. Also making sure it doesn't write it twice.

This is for my project at my client's side. I need to convert xml to text and I'm doing this with groovy and xslt. As the xml files are large, it takes a lot of time to get through the xml file to find the different 'value-off''s.

I've already this, but it gives me ALL the nodes and it's values, so each node more then once

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/currencies/record"></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:key name="names" match="*|@*" use="name()"/>

<xsl:template match="/currencies/record">
      <xsl:for-each select="//*">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>=<xsl:apply-templates select="current()/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<record deprecated="false"
           id="CUR00001"
           date.creation="2010-03-22"
           adm.status="current">
      <authority-code>AED</authority-code>
      <code-4217>AED</code-4217>
      <label>
         <lg.version lg="bul" script="Cyrillic">Дирхам на ОАЕ</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="ces">UAE dirham n. emirátský dirham</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="dan">Emiratarabisk dirham</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="deu" gender.grammar="M">VAE-Dirham</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="deu" number.grammar="P">VAE-Dirhams</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="fin">Arabiemiirikuntien dirhami</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="fra" gender.grammar="M">Dirham des Émirats arabes unis</lg.version>
         ...
      </label>
      <currency.subunit>
         <lg.version lg="bul" script="Cyrillic">филс</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="ces">fils</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="dan">fils</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="deu" gender.grammar="M">Fils</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="ell" script="Greek">φιλς</lg.version>
         <lg.version lg="eng" gender.grammar="N">fils</lg.version>
         ...
      <start.use>1990-01-01</start.use>
      <linkCOUid>COU0450</linkCOUid>
      <use.context>TED_SCHEMA</use.context>
   </record>
```

In my example "lg.version" is present a lot of times, I'm expecting it to be there just 1 time.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You defined a key, but you don't use it. Read: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Also as Groovy is based on the Java platform you should have an option to use XSLT 2 or 3 or XPath 2 or 3 or XQuery 3 with Saxon 9 where you have functions like `distinct-values` and grouping constructs (e.g. `xsl:for-each-group in XSLT, `for .. group by` in XQuery) instead of messing with XSLT 1.

Comment: I am wondering what your desired XML output  would look like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always say which version of XSLT you are using.

In XSLT 2.0 it is simply `distinct-values(//*/node-name())` (assuming that by "nodes" you really mean "elements").

If you're on 1.0 and can't move forward for some reason, use Muenchian grouping - which makes it much more complicated.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your time! As you can see in the first node the stylesheet mention 'Version 1.0', so I thouhgt that would have been clear enough?  :-)  Nevertheless, indeed Muenchian grouping is far more worse then the 'normal' nodereadings. I've asked a developper to look into it, but he has a lot of work and I don't have much time to learn Muenchian grouping neither.... so for now, I rest my case  ;-)

Comment: Well, the fact that your stylesheet says version="1.0" doesn't mean that your processor won't accept XSLT 2.0, though I agree it's a clue that I missed. But since you're on Java, you have a choice between learning Muenchian grouping and moving forward to XSLT 2.0, then I would definitely recommend moving to XSLT 2.0. After all, 1.0 is 20 years old.